# How to translate multiple error for a single field while a form validation in react-intl?

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-intl

I have two validation rules for email field. So how i translate each rule for each validation.

```
  {formik.errors.email && formik.touched.email ? (
        <div className="form-validate-error"> <FormattedMessage id="errorRequired" 
        defaultMessage={formik.errors.email}/> 
   </div>) : null}
```